# sqlalchemy core: slow performance for a simple SELECT query comparing to sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I've been trying to optimize some of my code that reads from an `sqlite` database via `sqlalchemy`, it seemed that reading the db was taking quite a lot of time.

I've reduced it to the following test: read 5 million integers from an `sqlite` database.

Raw `sqlite3` implementation takes 1.2 seconds, whereas when I do it via sqlalchemy core, it takes 3.2 seconds.

After some profiling with py-spy I've noticed that most of the time is spent outside sqlite and rather in sqlalchemy itself -- and the time spent in sqlite is about 1 second, which matches the raw sqlite3 performance.

The most offending line performance-wise was [this](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/8503dc2e948908199cd8ba4e6b1d1ddcf92f4020/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py#L557).
I imagine converting a bare sqlite row to sqlachemy Row takes some time, so that's fair.

However I can't find a way to control that behaviour, e.g. ideally I need some sort of cursor that just returns bare tuples from sqlite without any additional processing by sqlalchemy.

If I simply set `make_row = None` in sqlalchemy itself it actually kinda achieves what I want, and runs in 2.2 seconds (although still a bit of overhead).
I tried to read the sqlalchemy code to understand what impacts `_row_getter` and what in the library could force it to be `None`, but didn't manage to find anything.

From sqlalchemy logs, it's the same query I'm running against `sqlite3

```
SELECT data.x
FROM data
```

I'm using latest sqlalchemy `2.0.20`, libsqlite version is `3.37.2`, python `3.10.4`.

```py
N = 5_000_000
# database with 5000000 ints
db_path = '/tmp/ints.sqlite'

# takes about 1.2s
def test_sqlite():
    import sqlite3
    total = 0
    last = None
    with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
        for (x,) in conn.execute('SELECT * FROM data'):
            total += 1
            last = x
    assert total == N  # just in case
    print(last)


# takes about 3.2s
def test_sqlalchemy():
    import sqlalchemy
    from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, text
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'sqlite:///{db_path}', echo=True)
    meta = MetaData()
    table_cache = Table('data', meta, Column('x', sqlalchemy.Integer))
    query = table_cache.select()
    total = 0
    last = None
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        rows = conn.execute(query)
        for (x,) in rows:
            total += 1
            last = x
    assert total == N  # just in case
    print(last)
```

Comment: Do you really want to measure the import time?

Comment: @Hermann12 it's negligible..
``` 
python3 -m timeit 'import sqlalchemy; from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, text'
500000 loops, best of 5: 588 nsec per loop
```

Comment: I don't think these are the same query but it probably doesn't matter but can you include the SQL generated by sqlalchemy?

Comment: Also what versions of the libraries are you using ?

Comment: @karlicoss Testing this on my machine it seems that bare sqlite isn't operating within a transaction (Do you know if that is True?) whereas by default sqlalchemy is going to operate in a transaction(I can see that with echo).  Only seems to be a minor difference though but I think there might be a lot of quirks that we aren't considering.

Answer (score 0):

On my dinosaur toaster using yield per seems to make a little difference, I have no idea how sqlite is handling this, if it just pulls it all into memory immediately or if there is any sort of buffering.  Maybe I'll expand this later.

```py
import sys
import sqlite3
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, text
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from datetime import datetime

N = 5_000_000
# database with 5000000 ints
db_path = '/tmp/ints.sqlite'

# takes about 1.2s
def test_sqlite():
    total = 0
    last = None
    with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:
        conn.execute('BEGIN')
        for (x,) in conn.execute('SELECT x FROM data'):
            total += 1
            last = x
        conn.execute('ROLLBACK')

    assert total == N  # just in case
    print(last)


# takes about 3.2s
def test_sqlalchemy():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'sqlite:///{db_path}', echo=False)
    meta = MetaData()
    table_cache = Table('data', meta, Column('x', sqlalchemy.Integer))
    query = select(table_cache.c.x).execution_options(yield_per=100000, max_row_buffer=10000)
    total = 0
    last = None
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        for (x,) in conn.execute(query):
            total += 1
            last = x
    assert total == N  # just in case
    print(last)

def insert_numbers(conn, numbers):
    s = f"""INSERT INTO data ('x') VALUES ({"),(".join(numbers)})"""
    conn.execute(s)


def create_test_db():
    total = 0
    last = None
    with sqlite3.connect(db_path) as conn:

        conn.execute('CREATE TABLE data (x int) ')
        x = 1
        numbers = []
        while x <= N:
            numbers.append(str(x))
            if len(numbers) == 1000:
                insert_numbers(conn, numbers)
                numbers = []
            x += 1
        if numbers:
            insert_numbers(conn, numbers)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'sqlite':
        b4 = datetime.now()
        test_sqlite()
        print ('sqlite', datetime.now() - b4)
    elif len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'sqlalchemy':
        b4 = datetime.now()
        test_sqlalchemy()
        print ('sqlalchemy', datetime.now() - b4)
    else:
        print ('Creating test db')
        create_test_db()
```